# Form is not Submitting any Value using Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
In Model:


public int TeacherCourseAssignId { set; get; }
    public int TeacherID { set; get; }
    public decimal TeacherRemainingCredit { set; get; }
    public int CourseId { set; get; }
    public string CourseName { set; get; }
    public decimal CourseCredit { set; get; }


In controller:
```

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TeacherCourseAssign(int departmentId, int teacherId, int courseId)
    {

```
    ViewBag.Departments = GetDepartments();
    return View();
}
public ActionResult SaveTeacherCourseAssign(TeacherCourseAssign teacherCourseAssign)
{

    ViewBag.Departments = GetDepartments();
    ViewBag.Message = teacherCourseAssignManager.Save(teacherCourseAssign);
    ModelState.Clear(); 
    return View();
}
public JsonResult SaveTeacheCourseAssign(TeacherCourseAssign teacherCourseAssign)
{
    //Code
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetTeachersByDepartmentId(int deptId)
{
    var teachers = GetTeacher();
    var teacherList = teachers.Where(a => a.DepartmentId == deptId).ToList();

    return Json(teacherList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetCoursesByDepartmentId(int deptId)
{
    var courses = GetCourses();
    var courseList = courses.Where(a => a.DepartmentId == deptId).ToList();
    return Json(courseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetTeachersInfoByTeacherId(int teacherId)
{
    var teachers = GetTeacher();
    var teacherInfo = teachers.Where(t => t.TeacherID == teacherId).ToList();

    return Json(teacherInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public JsonResult GetCoursesInfoByCourseId(int courseId)
{
    var courses = GetCourses();
    var courseList = courses.Where(c => c.CourseId == courseId).ToList();
    return Json(courseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In View:

```
@model Last.Models.TeacherCourseAssign


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Teacher Course Assign";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Teacher Course Assign</h2>

<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="departmentId">Select Department</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="departmentId" id="departmentId">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    @foreach (var department in ViewBag.Departments)
                    {
                        <option value="@department.DeptId">@department.DeptName</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="teacherId">Teacher</label></td>
            <td>
                <select name="teacherId" id="teacherId"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CreditToBeTaken)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CreditToBeTaken)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(r => r.TeacherRemainingCredit)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.TeacherRemainingCredit)

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td><label for="courseId"></label></td>
            <td>

                <select name="courseId" id="courseId"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(n => n.CourseName)</td>
            <td>

               @Html.TextBoxFor(n => n.CourseName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(c => c.CourseCredit)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CourseCredit)
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>




        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Assign" class="btn btn-default" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#departmentId").change(function() {


                var dept = $("#departmentId").val();
                $("#teacherId").empty();
                $("#courseId").empty();

                var json = { deptId: dept };
                //$("#teacherId").append('<option value="">Select</option>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetTeachersByDepartmentId", "TeacherCourseAssign")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#teacherId").append('<option value="">Select</option>');
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                            $("#teacherId").append('<option value=' + value.TeacherID + '>' + value.TeacherName + '</option>');

                        });
                    }
                });

                //   $("#courseId").append('<option value="">Select</option>');


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCoursesByDepartmentId", "TeacherCourseAssign")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#courseId").append('<option value="">Select</option>');
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $("#courseId").append('<option value=' + value.CourseId + '>' + value.CourseCode + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#teacherId").change(function() {
                var tech = $("#teacherId").val();
                var json = { teacherId: tech };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetTeachersInfoByTeacherId", "TeacherCourseAssign")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $("#CreditToBeTaken").val(value.CreditToBeTaken);

                            $("#TeacherRemainingCredit").val(value.CreditToBeTaken);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#courseId").change(function() {
                var tech = $("#courseId").val();
                var json = { courseId: tech };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCoursesInfoByCourseId", "TeacherCourseAssign")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $("#courseName").val(value.CourseName);
                            $("#CourseCredit").val(value.Credit);

                        });
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    </script>
}
```

My Cascading DropDown for department, course and teacher Info is working fine. but when I click on submit. it is not submitting any value to my post controller SaveTeacherCourseAssign(). want to know am i submitting my model in a wrong way?

Comment: Which value are you expecting and what is not available ?

Comment: as my model i want to pass those all data to my database. but as my view is loading with all data which i passed to it. cascading ajax call is working completely fine. but when i press submit with my selected data.. nothing happens. it just clears my text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to hit the controller at all? By default, all controllers actions listen to GET requests, so if you can't hit it, you would have to decorate it with `[HttpPost]` in order to hit it.

Also, I don't see any ajax request that's targeting it. Unless it's the form, at which point you might want to explicitly put an action attribute on it if the page/view name is not the same.

If you're in fact hitting a breakpoint when you submit, are you just getting a null object?

Comment: yes my Get request is working properly. is loading with all my desired dropdowns and values...

Comment: I'm talking about your `SaveTeacherCourseAssign` endpoint. Can you hit it?

Comment: So, a) Put `action="SaveTeacherCourseAssign"` (or whatever your controller/action path is, which can also be resolved via `@Url.Action("method", "controller")` and b) Decorate your endpoint with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: have already tried that.. but its not passing any value to my model.

Comment: OK, looking at your other posts... if you're going to be submitting via AJAX, you might want you do the following (on top of what I had suggested already): For starters, bind a jQuery function to `$('form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //Do whatever else you need here });` First, you need to bind your form to be able to send it over asynchronously, and second, the `e.preventDefault()` ensures that you don't submit it synchronously.

Comment: do i have to submit with ajax here? do complete this? is this what i am missing?

Comment: Yes, you do... if you want to, that is (you can always POST traditionally). You would have to serialize the form and then submit it. The code you're using for the other AJAX calls should give you a good boilerplate on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you have your `form` element but it doesn't have any `action` property. You have to add it like:

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm"
action="@Url.Action("your_action_method_name" , "your_controller_name")" >
```

I think this is what you are missing.

Comment: tried  <form method="POST" id="myForm"
action="@Url.Action("your_action_method_name" , "your_controller_name")" > ,but no change.. i want to know is my data not binding properly for the model?

Comment: You replaced the fields with your action name and controller name, right?
It should be <form method="POST" id="myForm" action="@Url.Action("SaveTeacherCourseAssign" , "TeacherCourseAssign")" > in your case